# Why does Python act like my dict is a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a sorted dict class as a way to mess around with dunder methods. I know `collections.OrderedDict` exists.

When I try to overload `__getitem__` or `__setitem__`, Python acts as if I am trying to index a list with a string key. Here is my code for the class:

```py
class SortedDict:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.map = dict(kwargs)
        self._sort()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.map)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.map[key]

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        self.map[name] = value

    def keys(self):
        return self.map.keys()

    def add(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            self.map[key] = kwargs[key]
        self._sort()

        indices = dict()
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            indices[key] = self.index(key)
        return indices

    def remove(self, *args):
        for key in args:
            self.map.pop(key)

    def index(self, key: str):
        keys = list()
        for dict_key in self.map.keys():
            keys.append(dict_key)
        return keys.index(key)

    def contains(self, key: str):
        return key in self.map

    def _sort(self):
        self.map = sorted(self.map)
```

When I execute the following code to test `__getitem__`:

```py
from sorted_dict import SortedDict
test_dict= SortedDict(test1=1, test2=2, a=2, b=3)
print(test_dict['test1'])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Code\DMC2\mapping_editor\tree.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(test_dict['test1'])
  File "c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Code\DMC2\mapping_editor\sorted_dict.py", line 11, in __getitem__
    return self.map[key]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I get a similar error when trying to use `__setitem__`. I am using VS code, and when I hover my cursor over `self.map` in either of those functions the type is shown as `dict[str, Any] | list[str]`. If I print the type of `self.map` in either of the functions, it prints `<class 'list'>`, but when I print the class of `self.map` in the constructor it prints as `<class 'dict'>`, which is what I would expect. When I print `self.map` in the `__setitem__` or `__getitem__` functions it prints as a list of the keys, but in the constructor it prints as a dictionary would. What am I missing?

Comment: In the `_sort` method you change `self.map` to a list, `sorted` returns a list

Comment: If you believe dicts to be unordered, you need to maintain a separate list of keys in whatever order you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `sorted(self.map)` returns a list of the sorted `map` keys. To get a sorted dictionary you can do

```
def _sort(self):
    self.map = dict(sorted(self.map.items()))
```

This will give you `{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'test1': 1, 'test2': 2}`.

Comment: But that would also immediately undo the sort if dict wasn't already ordered.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't follow, why would it undo the sort?

Comment: My initial assumption was that OP wanted to pretend that dicts are unordered, but I realize on second reading that that's not the case.